# Selenium not able to find particular elements on slow loading page

Tags: python, xcode, selenium, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape the website basketball-reference and am running into an issue I can't seem to solve. I am trying to grab the box score element for each game played. This is something I was able to easily do with urlopen but b/c other portions of the site require Selenium I thought I would rewrite the entire process with Selenium

Issue seems to be that even if I wait to scrape until I to see the first element load using WebDriverWait, when I then move forward to grabbing the elements I get nothing returned.

One thing I found interesting is if I did a full site print using my results from urlopen w/ something like print (uClient.read()) I would get roughly 300 more lines of html after beautifying compared to doing the same with print (driver.page_source). Even if I put an ImplicitlyWait set for 5 minutes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/')
driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[1]')))


box = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('game_summary expanded nohover')

print (box)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Increase the waiting time from 10 to 30 and see if it helps.

Comment: I upped to both 30 and 60 and in both cases returned no results still.

Comment: find_elements will return if at least one item is found... add a sleep before using it... (or catch Stale Element exceptions by triggering a method on the webelement(s)... if caught, re-do the find_elements call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, it is working in my computer. Do let me know if you still face problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/')
driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[1]')))

boxes = driver.wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=\"game_summary expanded nohover\"]")))

print("Number of Elements Located : ", len(boxes))

for box in boxes:
    print(box.text)
    print("-----------")

driver.quit()
```

If it resolves your problem then please mark it as answer. Thanks

Comment: This indeed worked. I didn't realize there was a .presence_of_all_elements_located class. One oddity I did note was the fact that using Selenium is producing double the amount of div class='game_summary expanded nohover'. However once printed, it shows the first six as blank and then the actual six that I see while inspecting the html. Not a huge deal, but curious if you might know why that is occurring. It didn't when I used to perform this action in uClient.read()....that was the only way I noticed as I compared the results of both.

Comment: Yes, i am also getting 12 elements. to get the exactly what you want you can use this xpath - `//div[@class="section_heading"]/following-sibling::div/div[@class="game_summary expanded nohover"]`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the site doesn't require selenium at all. All the data is there through a simple requests (it's just in the Comments of the html, would just need to parse that). Secondly, you can grab the box scores quite easily with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/')

for idx, table in enumerate(dfs[:-2]):
    print (table)
    if (idx+1)%3 == 0:
        print("-----------")
```